# Process not giving up child pid

Tags: multithreading, bash

I want the child and parent pid.  So I do this:

```
function x { echo $1 $$; }
```

Now when I do the following I expect the function x to have the parent and child pids:

```
x $$ &
```

However, x only has the parent pid.  How can I get the function to run as a separate process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `$BASHPID`:

```
#! /bin/bash

function x { echo $$  $BASHPID;}

x & child=$!; wait ; echo $child
```

Output:

```
bash  test.sh 
1191 1195
1195
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something to do with the scope of `$$`, it's already been globally evaluated when you start the script. The function is definitely running in a separate process. You can get the PID of the child with `$!`

```
function x { 
   echo $1 $$; 
}

x $$ &
echo "forked process: $!"
```